# Mongoid query by a array with size in a range

Tags: mongoid

How can I query by a array with size in a range?

Documents:

```
Foo { foo_array: [{name: "item_1"},{name: "item_2}] }
Foo { foo_array: [{name: "item_1"}] }
Foo { foo_array: [{name: "item_1"},{name: "item_2},{name: "item_3}] }
```

For instance, I try to get: **Foo objects which foo_array field has between 2 or 3 items.**

Something like:

```
Foo.where(:foo_array.with_size => [2,3])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can query arrays by index and then check if the element at the desired index exists. For example:

```
Foo.where(
  # something at index 1 means that the size is at least two
  'foo_array.1' => { :$exists => true },
  # nothing at index 3 means that the size is at most three
  'foo_array.3' => { :$exists => false }
)
```